# Binding events to KineticJS objects using anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am working on a project using Canvas and KineticJS. I load/create a number of nodes and edges, and have desired functionality when I interact with these under various circumstances.

At the moment I'm binding event handlers to these objects as they're created using anonymous functions. Something like this:

```
Node.prototype.setupNode = function(x, y) {

    this.visual.on('tap', function(e) {
        console.log(this.id);
    });

    ...
}
```

If I have a couple of event handlers to bind for each item, some of which are a fair number of lines of code, and I'm often binding a few hundred node and edge objects, are there more optimal ways of binding these events to these objects so that I can increase performance and decrease load time and resource usage?

Thanks in advance for any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named function and then pass it's reference to the event binding function, like this:

```
function handleTap (e) {
   //your code
}

Node.prototype.setupNode = function(x, y) {
    this.visual.on('tap', handleTap);
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I create function handleTap() inside the Node.prototype.setupNode function rather than outside it, does it consume more resources (by being constructed every time setupNode is called)?

Comment: JS engines do a lot of work to optimize the code. So, I am guessing that the JS interpreter will already be doing such an optimization wherever possible. But, it is always better to optimize the code yourself as much as you can, without relying on the code optimizers.